# Class CustomExceptionController does not exist Symfony4

Tags: symfony, twig, yaml

For a application, I would like to create a custom error 404 page in symfony 4.
But Symfony after have follow the documentation, he out in all the page :

```
Invalid service "App\Controller\CustomExceptionController": class "App\Controller\CustomExceptionController" does not exist.
```

I don't know why he can't find this class while I have all the plugins necessary for create a custom error page.

#### error404.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block main %}
    <h1>Page not found</h1>

    <p>
        The requested page couldn't be located. Checkout for any URL
        misspelling or <a href="{{ path('home') }}">return to the homepage</a>.
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

#### services.yaml

```
# This file is the entry point to configure your own services.
# Files in the packages/ subdirectory configure your dependencies.

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: 'fr'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{DependencyInjection,Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

    App\Controller\CustomExceptionController:
        public: true
        arguments:
            $debug: '%kernel.debug%'
```

#### twig.yaml

```
twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
    debug: '%kernel.debug%'
    strict_variables: '%kernel.debug%'
    exception_controller: App\Controller\ExceptionController::showException
```

#### the error page

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to modify the template for the 404 error page, then you don't have to create a new exception controller, just override the error template `error404.html.twig` as described [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/error_pages.html#example-404-error-template). This is the easiest way to adjust any error page.

However if you want your custom logic to generate error pages, then you have to write your own exception controller, i.e. you have to actually implement the class `App\Controller\CustomExceptionController`, not only point to it in your yaml configs. The easiest way is to extend the default [ExceptionController](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/4.2/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Controller/ExceptionController.php) and override the `showAction()` and/or `findTemplate()` methods. Then point to your controller in the twig configuration:

```
# twig.yaml
twig:
    [...] 
    exception_controller: App\Controller\CustomExceptionController::showAction
```

Comment: Ok, but when I have put the ExceptionController in my project (polyescape/src/Controller/CustomExceptionController) I have two new error :

RuntimeException

The autoloader expected class "App\Controller\CustomExceptionController\ExceptionController" to be defined in file "/home/aubry/Documents/projet_escape_game/polyescape/vendor/composer/../../src/Controller/CustomExceptionController/ExceptionController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo.

Comment: And I have this error :

 LoaderLoadException

The autoloader expected class "App\Controller\CustomExceptionController\ExceptionController" to be defined in file "/home/aubry/Documents/projet_escape_game/polyescape/vendor/composer/../../src/Controller/CustomExceptionController/ExceptionController.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo in /home/aubry/Documents/projet_escape_game/polyescape/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/home/aubry/Documents/projet_escape_game/polyescape/config/services.yaml").

Comment: Your exception class `CustomExceptionController` and file with the same name has to be located in `polyescape/src/Controller/`. The namespace should be `App\Controller`. If it doesn't work, please upload your exception class.

Comment: Hum, now, I haven't error but we are agree that twig file for the custom error must be in : polyescape/templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error.html.twig ?

Because he can't show this file.

Comment: For the 404 error you need `polyescape/templates/bundles/TwigBundle/Exception/error404.html.twig`

Comment: But I have a file which name error404.html.twig, But it's doesn't work